# How to print array shape inside dictionary function in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am having dictionary function with array inside value and I am unable to print shape of array inside dictionary function

```
import numpy as np
abc = {"a":np.array([[np.array([1,2,3])]])}
a = abc.values()
print(a)
```

For this I'll get output

```
dict_values([array([[[1, 2, 3]]])])
```

But when I print

```
print(a.shape)
```

I am getting such error

```
AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Alright dictionary function does not have shape I agree, but how can I print the shape of the variable a or array

Comment: `a` is `dict_values` object it doesn't have an attribute `shape`. `a` has a *Numpy* array inside which has an attribute `shape`, `a[0].shape` should give you the shape.

Comment: Tried it too it gives result, 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable

Comment: My bad use `list(a)[0].shape`

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the returned `dict_values` object and get the shape of each item.

```
import numpy as np

abc = {"a":np.array([[np.array([1,2,3])]])}
vals = abc.values()

for a in vals:
    print(a, a.shape)
```

Alternatively, if you know you only have one value or only want the first value, you can convert the `dict_values` object to a list first and index into that list.

```
print(list(vals)[0].shape)
```